# Get object out of array if it contains value of another item in another array

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects:

```js
const raceOptions = [
  { value: "AmericanIndianOrAlaskaNative", label: "American Indian or Alaska Native" },
  { value: "AmericanIndianOrAlaskaNativeOther", label: "American Indian or Alaska Native Other" },
  { value: "Asian", label: "Asian" },
  { value: "AsianIndian", label: "Asian Indian" },  
];
```

I also have another array:

```js
var incomingArray = ['Asian', 'AmericanIndianOrAlaskanPacific', 'NativeHawaiian', 'BlackorAfricanAmerican']
```

How can I create a new array of objects only if the `incomingArray` has values that match the `raceOptions` value?

If `incomingArray` contains 'Asian' I want a new array that will contain `{ value: "Asian", label: "Asian" }` which comes from the `raceOptions` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const raceOptions = [
  { value: "AmericanIndianOrAlaskaNative", label: "American Indian or Alaska Native" },
  { value: "AmericanIndianOrAlaskaNativeOther", label: "American Indian or Alaska Native Other" },
  { value: "Asian", label: "Asian" },
  { value: "AsianIndian", label: "Asian Indian" },

];
let incomingArray = ['Asian', 'AmericanIndianOrAlaskanPacific', 'NativeHawaiian', 'BlackorAfricanAmerican'];
let res = raceOptions.filter(x => incomingArray.includes(x.value));
console.log(res);
```